# My code is not working due to an error when inserting data into the database

Tags: sql, vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form2    
    
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        
        Dim A As New SqlConnection
        Dim cmdd As New SqlCommand
        Dim R As SqlDataReader

        A.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\SurAj\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\RPS\connectivity.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        A.Open()
        cmdd.Connection = A
        cmdd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdd.CommandText = "select * from T where emailid='" & emailid.Text & "' "
        R = cmdd.ExecuteReader
        If R.HasRows Then
            MsgBox("ADD Another Email Id", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error: Try Again")
            A.Close()

        Else
            A.Close()
            A.Open()
             cmdd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO T values('" & fullnames.Text & "','" & emailid.Text & "','" & loginU.Text & "','" & loginP.Text & "')", A)

             If (fullnames.Text = String.Empty Or emailid.Text = String.Empty Or loginU.Text = String.Empty Or loginP.Text = String.Empty) Then
            MessageBox.Show("You missed some details", "ERROR")
            Else
            cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Successfully registered.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
            Me.Hide()
            Form3.Show()
            fullnames.Clear()
            emailid.Clear()
            loginU.Clear()
            loginP.Clear()

             End If
            A.Close()
        End If
        A.Close()
        '        Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox("Error")
        'End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get an error at `cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery`:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
> Additional information: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
> even though all columns are mentioned. What's wrong? I'm not getting it.

Comment: Welcome, take the [tour]. You should read up about sql injection risks and change your code to avoid it. Can you include details of the error you're getting?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: Additional information: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T] (
    [Id]        INT          NOT NULL,
    [fullnames] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [emailid]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [loginU]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [loginP]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);         This the table definition

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: Is your ID field the primary key? I see it is not an identity field so how are you guaranteeing uniqueness?  You have not provided a value for this field, yet it is a required field.

Answer (score 1):

Your table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T] 
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL, 
    [fullnames] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [emailid] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [loginU] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    [loginP] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
);
```

and your insert statement only inserts value for `fullnames`, `emailid`, `loginU` and `loginP` - but **NOT** for `Id`:

```
 cmdd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO T VALUES('" & fullnames.Text & "','" & emailid.Text & "','" & loginU.Text & "','" & loginP.Text & "')", A)
```

--> you're **NOT** proving values for **all** columns in your table.

Furthermore, as I mentioned in comments - you should ***NEVER EVER*** concatenate together your SQL statements like this - use **parameters** - ***ALWAYS***!

Also, it is a generally accepted best practice to **list** your columns of the table you're inserting into.

So all in all, your insert statement should be something like:

```
string insertQry = @"INSERT INTO T (id, fullnames, emailid, loginU, loginP) 
                     VALUES (@id, @fullnames, @emailid, @loginU, @loginP);";
cmdd.CommandText = insertQry;

// add the parameters and their values here
```

Answer (score 0):

I have divided the code into user interface and data access. The user interface knows nothing about where the data is being sent. It could be Oracle, MS Access or even a text file. It doesn't matter to the user interface.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Do your validation first
    If fullnames.Text = String.Empty OrElse emailid.Text = String.Empty OrElse loginU.Text = String.Empty OrElse loginP.Text = String.Empty Then
        MessageBox.Show("You missed some details", "ERROR")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim id As Integer 'I don't know where this value is coming from
    Try
        Dim inserts = InsertUser(id, fullnames.Text, emailid.text, loginU.Text, loginP.Text)
        If inserts = 1 Then
            MsgBox("Successfully registered.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
            Me.Hide()
            Form3.Show()
            fullnames.Clear()
            emailid.Clear()
            loginU.Clear()
            loginP.Clear()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Addition not successful. The email already exists.")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Likewise, the `InsertUser` function where the data is coming from. It could be a Web app, a WPF application or WinForms.

The command text combines checking if the email already exists in the database and the actually insert.

`Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even it there is an error.

**Always use Parameters.** http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

```
    Private Function InsertUser(id As Integer, name As String, email As String, user As String, pword As String) As Integer
    Dim RecordsEntered As Integer
    Dim sql = "If Not Exists(Select * From T Where emailid = @emailid) 
                Insert Into T (Id, fullnames, emailid, loginU, loginP) 
                Values (@Id, @fullnames, @emailid, @loginU, @loginP);"
    Using A As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\SurAj\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\RPS\connectivity.mdf;Integrated Security=True"),
        cmdd As New SqlCommand(sql, A)
        With cmdd.Parameters
            .Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
            .Add("@fullnames", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = name
            .Add("@emailid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = email
            .Add("@loginU", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = user
            .Add("@loginP", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = pword
        End With
        A.Open()
        RecordsEntered = cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery 'Returns -1 if no records are inserted
    End Using
    Return RecordsEntered
End Function
```

Another problem which I did not is address is passwords. They should NEVER be stored as plain text. Have a look at encryption.